# Creating text in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I followed this tutorial in order to get a better understanding of classes found [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix--active-5789).

I did everything correctly up to step 10, but when I went to export the SWF I got a blank screen. I get an error in the compiler that says "expecting identifier before dot."

I don't know what this means but you can download my files and take a look and hopefully give me an answer, thanks!

Here is my code :

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import.text.TextField;

    public class documentclass extends MovieClip 
    {       
        public function documentclass() 
        {
            // constructor code
            var tf:TextField = new TexfField();
            addChild(tf);
            tf.text = "Hello Wrold";                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. You generally get the line number for where the error occurs... Adding the code here makes your question more answerable, and will help others who have the same problem in future.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is fired by this line, there is a dot (`.`) after `import` :

```
import.text.TextField;
```

which even you don't need because you've already imported the `TextField` class.

Then you have a little typing error in this line :

```
var tf:TextField = new TexfField();
```

which should be :

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();     // new TextField, with "t" not "f"
```

so your final code can be like this :

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class documentclass extends MovieClip 
    {       
        public function documentclass() 
        {
            // constructor code
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            addChild(tf);
            tf.text = "Hello Wrold";                
        }
    }

}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: To SpecekdGames: Most programming languages (if not all) are ultra picky on names and paths. So very precise typing is required at all time. Your code understands "import flash.text.TextField;" because it points to a very precise location, your code understands "TextField" because it is a known class but "Textfield" on the other hand means nothing and does not exist. So coding = ultra precise typing, get used to it right now as you are learning.